# NUnit. How to automatically generate tests?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

Is there any software that simplifies creation of tests? Most of the contents of tests is pretty repetitive, so I thought someone might have automated this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have a look on [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/Pex) - it allows to generate tests for NUnit, MbUnit and others. Here's [an article](http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/7963) on using this tool.

Answer (score 0):

The testing framework in VS2008 does automatically generate tests for a class - if this is really what you want!

Answer (score 0):

There are some good options below, I must admit I haven't used them as I write all tests myself.

- [edwinyeh](http://www.freewebs.com/edwinyeah/)
- [nunitgenerator
  addin](http://forge.novell.com/modules/xfmod/project/?nunitgenaddin)
- [nunit test generated
  kellermansoftware](http://www.kellermansoftware.com/p-30-nunit-test-generator.aspx)
- [doubler](http://jayflowers.com/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=38)